# Blender render doesn't display skybox while opengl render does

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have used a [skybox image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5PR8wODbC6tTGczeG9VOFZQbnM/view?usp=sharing) that I find on a [website](http://www.braynzarsoft.net/vision/index.php?p=VT&texture=23&vi=y) and wrapped a cube to make a skybox. The final blender file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5PR8wODbC6teWpmSkczVHNXSmM/view?usp=sharing).

When I render image using <kbd>F12</kbd>, the result is blank. However, if I make OpenGL render image, the result is as expected. What is wrong with the normal rendering, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you set for the cube an "Image or movie" texture type pointing to that image? Are the texture's coordinates set to UV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem resides in your material; You just need to check 'Face Textures', under the options tab of your cube material.

[image]